# Content Query WebPart, multiple title fields

Tags: sharepoint-server, content-query-web-part

I have added a cCntent query webpart and configured it, and it is working good.

But in the title field, instead of just one source field, can I add two sources?

What I want is: My list that is connected to CQWP has 2 fields named `Name` and `Lastname`. Is there any way to show both of these columns in the CQWP title field?

Or can this be done only in the description field?

I tried as follows but it does not work.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do this is by creating a calculated column on the list, 'FullName', that just concatenates first and last name. You can then use 'FullName' in the WebPart's Title field.

Comment: yes I have done that and it works perfectly but i have 4 to 5 information that needs to be shown in description. Can I do that

Comment: Sure, just concatenate all of them in the calculated column. It's a lot easier than editing the XSLT template.